# Updating dropdown list picked values when the source data is changed at a later date

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In the screenshot below, column C contains dropdown lists populated with col A source values. Let's consider the following scenario

1. A2 initial value is "choice B"
2. In C1, "choice B" is selected
3. A2 value is edited to "choice B - just modified"

Unfortunately, C1 value won't update and triggers a warning. How do I go about it so that dropdown list values get updated if their respective source cell gets modified?

Going further, I intend to be using it with IMPORTRANGE, to be able to use the same source values across multiple Google Sheets workbooks. So that needs to be accounted for.

Is that something that is at all possible, be it natively or using 3rd party plugins?

[image]

Comment: if this is possible then only with a script

Comment: I think that the simple trigger of OnEdit can be used. But, the method for editing the cells of column "A" is important for creating a script. If you always edit cells by manually inputting value, the script will be simple. But, when you want to edit the cells by copying and pasting the values to column "A", the script might be a bit complicated. By the way, I cannot understand `Going further, I intend to be using it with IMPORTRANGE, to be able to use the same source values across multiple Google Sheets workbooks. So that needs to be accounted for.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it?

Comment: There could be a workaround (not necessarily a full solution, but a workaround). The thing is: will always Choice B be the second option in the list even If the value changes?? (Meaning, won't the values change their order?)

Answer (score 1):

It could be done with something like this but I think it could get messed up pretty easily:

```
function ddd() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getSheetByName("Sheet0");
  const rg = sh.getRange("A2:A");
  let dv = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInRange(rg).setAllowInvalid(true).build();
  sh.getRange("B2:B").setDataValidation(dv);
}

function onEdit(e) {
  e.source.toast("Entry");
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if(sh.getName() == "Sheet0" && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.range.rowStart > 1 ) {
    e.source.toast("Gate1");
    sh.getRange("B2:B" + sh.getLastRow()).getValues().flat().forEach((el,i) => {if(el == e.oldValue) {
      sh.getRange(i + 2, 2).setValue(e.value);
    }})
  }
}
```